# Permalinks changed with Wordpress 4.9

Tags: permalinks

I've upgraded to Wordpress 4.9 and now all of my permalinks seem to include `/index.php/` before the page name. This is not how I set up the permalinks originally.

All I want displayed is `www.myurl.com/subpage` NOT `www.myurl.com/index.php/subpage`.

I've checked my htaccess file and it appears to be fine, I've also disabled all plugins and have checked my Permalinks structure in the Wordpress backend and still have no solution to the issue.

htaccess file is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If anyone has any insight to what may be causing this issue, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: got snippet of htaccess?

Comment: try saving the permalinks again to flush

Comment: You can answer your own question. It is the preferred method, instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! Seems that the `<Directory>` in the .conf file in Apache2 was not configured correctly.

An example of a correctly configured .conf file is as follows:

```
# domain: exampleurl.com
# public: /var/www/html/exampleurl.com/public_html/

<Directory /var/www/html/exampleurl.com/public_html>
Require all granted
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin support@exampleurl.com
ServerName  exampleurl.com
ServerAlias www.exampleurl.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/exampleurl.com/public_html

ErrorLog  /var/www/html/exampleurl.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/exampleurl.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Including `AllowOverride All` seems to fix the permalink issue.

Remember to run `service apache2 reload` in Terminal once you overwrite your .conf file.

Comment: Wow. You people  downvoting are savage AF.